# wrong date calculation for 'asked X months ago'

Tags: bug, questions

Following question:
[Apple Watchkit simulator issue: SPErrorInvalidBundleNoGizmoBinaryMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286571)

was asked on the 2nd of February 2015.

On the right I see following today (3rd of April 2015, 12.23 pm CET):

[image: Asked date/active date/viewed]

But that should be 2 months ago since 2nd of April, 9pm CET I think.
Is this a bug or do I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relative date display uses 30 days for a month, not calendar months.

As such it is 59 and a half days since the question was posted. After 9PM CET (20:00 UTC) it'll change to 2 months.